# Firebase restrict access to owner

Tags: javascript, firebase

Let say I'm using firebase to create a blog, there is multiple `authors` each writing their own `posts`.

So there is a `posts` collection and a `authors` collection with following rules:

- An author can create a post if authenticated
- An author can read each others post if authenticated
- An author can edit only his own posts

---

I've two questions, first, which database schema should I use?

- One `authors` collection and a separate `posts` collection
- One `authors` collection with `posts` embedded for each author

Second, which security rule should I use?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
  // to complete ..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you can use ng-show, ng-hide but this is not the best solution. Here is a link to how DoubleClick Campaign Manager handles user auth. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4F6Csor-S1cNThqekp4NUZCSmc/edit

Second: you can write your rules in this fashion - below, changing the values as needed.

```
{
    "rules": {
      "products": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      },
       "sectest": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "(newData.child('admin').child(auth.uid).exists()) || 
            (data.exists() && data.child('admin').child(auth.uid).val() == auth.uid) ||
            (root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/isadmin').exists())" 
      },
      "users": {
        ".write": true,
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      },
      "venders": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      },
      "channels": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
}
```

Check out this angular-blog example: https://github.com/yearofmoo/hexo-angular-blog-example

Comment: Nice example rules Mike! I had been looking at the Firebase chat rules as an example, but those were incredibly complex. Your sample is way better. In case anyone wants to verify that Mike's example is more readable, these are the rules of Firebase's Firechat example: https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json

Comment: This set is quite a bit simpler and nicer as a template than Firechat--which is a very sophisticated app (not meant as an example):  https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-revisiting-advanced-example. Agreed that Mikes are also quite nice!